# Jetty Connectors - How to create multiple websocket handlers

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, java-websocket

For a client-server app I create the following server that listens to port 8080 using a connector.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;




public class ProjectController {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server();

    ServerConnector primary=new ServerConnector(server);
    primary.setPort(8080);
    primary.setName("Primary");
    server.addConnector(primary);

    ServerConnector secondary=new ServerConnector(server);
    secondary.setPort(4321);
    secondary.setName("Secondary");
    server.addConnector(secondary);

    WebSocketHandler primaryHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
            factory.register(PrimarySocketHandler.class);
        }
    };


    server.setHandler(primaryHandler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

}

This connector has PrimarySocketHandler as context with @WebSocket annotation:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;


@WebSocket
public class PrimarySocketHandler {

    DataRetriever dr;
    String reply;

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("Close: statusCode=" + statusCode + ", reason=" + reason);
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + t.getMessage());
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {

        System.out.println("Connected");

    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {

        dr=new DataRetriever();
        try {
            reply=dr.retrieveQuotes(message);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            session.getRemote().sendString(reply);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to open a parallel connection from the client on a different port using a second connector. Can I create a new websocket handler (class) and map it to the new connector? If so, how?

Basically, what I need is two "instances" of the server to listen to different ports simultaneously, so I need two handlers to handle incoming data from each port.

I'm also open to different approaches.